# Accessing tiered-relations result in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have tables with these structure: (other columns not included)

**am_user:**

user_id - primary key

username

password

**am_projects:**

project_id - primary key

project_name

**am_user_project:**

user_id

project_id

My ***User*** model has this relation:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'am_user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    public function userproject()
          {
              return $this->hasMany('App\UserProject', 'user_id', 'user_id');
          }
}
```

My ***UserProject*** has this relation:

```
class UserProject extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'am_user_project';
  protected $primaryKey = null;

  public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'user_id');
  }

  public function project()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Project', 'project_id', 'project_id');
  }
}
```

My ***Project*** has this relation:

```
class Project extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'am_project';
  protected $primaryKey = 'project_id';

  public function userproject()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\UserProject', 'project_id');
  }

}
```

I'd like to list all project_names per projects assigned to Authenticated user which I can get from this:

```
public function index() {
      $user = User::with(['userproject.project'])->find(Auth::id());
      return view('projects', compact('user'));

  }
```

and post this in blade like so:

```
  <div class="list-group">
                @foreach($user->userproject as $userproject)
                  @foreach($userproject->project as $project)
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ $project->project_name }}</span></a>
                  @endforeach
                @endforeach
  </div>
```

Is there a way to actually avoid multiple foreach like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redifine your many to many relationship.

Remove the UserProject Model.

Change the User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'am_user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function projects()
    {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
    }
}
```

Change the Project Model:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'am_project';
    protected $primaryKey = 'project_id';

    public function users()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Now you can get the user like this:

```
public function index() 
{
      $user = User::find(Auth::id());
      return view('projects', compact('user'));
}
```

And show it like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
        @foreach($user->projects as $project)
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ $project->project_name }}</span></a>
        @endforeach  
</div>
```

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: you meant to say remove the relation in App\UserProject and all relations pointing to App\UserProject from both User and Project models?

Comment: I mean to get rid of the App\UserProject model. It is not needed. In a many to many relationship, you only need the `am_user_project` table, not the model for this table.

Comment: thanks!!this works..I just had to specify the dimension table's name to both models, then add the appropriate field names in projects() relation inside App\User

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a has-many-through relationship. See the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Considering the columns of `am_user_project`, wouldn't a many to many relation be sufficient?

Comment: Yeah good call I didn't notice both the foreign keys on that table. Another option would be to use pivot() where needed.